# Have I deleted essential python files on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, system, local, bin

I initially downloaded python 3.9 from the website but tried to be smart later on and do it through home brew. I am wondering if anyone believes any damage has been caused by doing this/along the way. My intention was to clear out any unwanted installations.

I was following a guide perhaps quite haphazardly. I am using Big Sur 11.0.1.

Where the guide began suggesting caution, it said to remove all symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` that point to Python related files:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python*
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip*
```

Then the guide said to remove versions of Python in the Python framework:

```
$ sudo rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/*
```

I am left wondering why the input below generates this output, one which seems to be problematic whenever somebody else reports it.

```
% /usr/local/bin/python
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python
```

**Solution to ^ ;-)**

```
brew link python@3.9
```

***Finally, does anyone know if any python files (version 2.7 I believe) required by the os will have been damaged by those commands?***

Comment: You could see if there is python in `/usr/bin`. Otherwise you might have to reinstall python with the package or with brew.

Comment: You removed `/usr/local/bin/python`. Unless you replaced it with something new, you'll get an error.

Comment: Thank you both. Does anyone know if any python files (version 2.7 I believe) required by the os will have been damaged by those commands? I seem to have multiple Python.framework folders so I'm wondering how the command `$ sudo rm -Rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/*` would have determined which one to erase.

Comment: @theshea The `/usr/local/bin/python` was in fact located in `/usr/bin`